# Is it possible to have overflow-x: visible and overflow-y: scroll without a fixed width?

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-grid

Per [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) for the `overflow` property:

> Setting one axis to visible (the default) while setting the other to a different value results in visible behaving as auto.

This seems to border on useless (the prime scenario for the `overflow-x` and `-y` properties seems that it would be to set them to opposing values, no?) and necessitates hacks or wrappers. However it's not a new complaint, so I won't belabor the point.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41875208/1655411) seems to be the best solution I've managed to find and is the one that I've settled for. At this point, I've given up on the "elegant" solution I'd like to have and am just curious to see if a solution even exists.

**Is it possible to have a `grid` based sidebar+content set up without using `position: fixed` and setting a fixed width on the sidebar?**

[Here is a fiddle demonstrating the issue.](https://jsfiddle.net/5rgo1q96/36/) The main goal here is to allow the sidebar contents to scroll on a short viewport while also adhering to the `min-content` of the `grid-template-columns` layout.